# How to force all framebuffers to use GL_EXT_framebuffer_object instead of the GL_ARB_framebuffer_object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opengl, monogame

Whenever i try to create a new Windows OpenGl project in VS 2012 and I run it i get a 
`Unable to find an entry point named 'glBindFramebuffer' in DLL 'opengl32.dll'.`
I have done some research and in the github forums someone was able to patch it by forcing the framebuffers to use Gl_EXT_framebuffer instead of the ARB_framebuffer which is currently using
,since ARB needs OpenGl 3 to run and my graphics card only supports OpenGl 2.0. So my question is where can I find the attibute or place to change which openGl framebuffer it targets to GL_EXT_framebuffer.? is it by VS 2012? or CMD? if you dont understand or need more info please comment and i would be more than happy to supply it.

Answer (score 2):

Framebuffer Objects are availble as a ARB extension even for OpenGL-1.2 and onward. All you need to do is load the OpenGL calls through the extension mechanism. You can use [GLEW](http://glew.sf.net) for that. Note that the OpenGL-3 core framebuffer object calls are identical in their signature to the ARB calls and the ARB framebuffer objects also work in OpenGL-3.

Comment: im sorry i dont quite understand I downloaded GLEW, how do i load the OPENGL calls? sorry im new to all of this.

Comment: @Alan: If you Read The Fine Manual of GLEW, you'll see that you link GLEW as an additional library into your program. You include `GL/glew.h` instead of `GL/gl.h`. Then after you got a OpenGL context you call `glewInit();` which will make all the required preparations. BTW, it's OpenGL (the `pen` parts is lowercase).

Comment: ha yes my capitalization gets crazy but im getting a error with the #include seems that C# doesnt have this directive http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx

Comment: thank you for your time by the way, i really appreciate it. but since I cant use the #include what should I do here is the error of course...http://i.imgur.com/xGIDgEH.jpg

Comment: @Alan: Opps, my bad I didn't notice that C# tag (hint: you should put the language you use somewhere into the question itself). OpenGL bindings like OpenTK or SharpGL already take care of extension loading. No need for GLEW in that case. Do you use one of these frameworks?

Comment: ok if I look under refenrences I see the following Lidgren.Network , MonoGame.Framework , OpenTk , System , System.Xml, and Tao.Sdl. So I guess i use OpenTk

Comment: this is where the suggestion to call the EXT instead of ARB frameBuffer.  https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/998#issuecomment-10557969

Comment: I was checking my driver capabilities in this website [link](http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/device/Mobile%20Intel(R)%204%20Series%20Express%20Chipset%20Family)      and found that the version 8.15.10.2372 supports everything??? but the later ones dont im really confused.